# How to get back on home screen in Android Studio

Tags: android

I have made an side navigation tool bar, in which I have 4 fragments (Fragment A, B, C, D). I want that whenever user press back button in any fragment A,B,C,D. User will get back to MainActivity (HomeScreen).

MainActivity.java --

```html
package com.thechamp.ait;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private NavigationView navigationView;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);

        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int timeOfDay = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

        if(timeOfDay >= 0 && timeOfDay < 12){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Good Morning", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if(timeOfDay >= 12 && timeOfDay < 16){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Good Afternoon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if(timeOfDay >= 16 && timeOfDay < 21){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Good Evening", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if(timeOfDay >= 21 && timeOfDay < 24){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Good Night", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }




        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


    }



    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected( MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case    R.id.nav_about:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new AboutCollege()).commit();
                break;

            case    R.id.nav_Earnmoney:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new EarnMoney()).commit();
                break;

            case    R.id.nav_Feedback:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Feedback()).commit();
                break;
            case    R.id.nav_notice:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new NoticeBoard()).commit();
                break;
            case    R.id.nav_study:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new StudyMaterial()).commit();
                break;
            case    R.id.nav_support:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Support()).commit();
                break;
        }
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}}
```

Now here is Fragment D (feedback.java)

```html
package com.thechamp.ait;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class Feedback extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feedback, container, false);


        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
       





           return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the behavior you want is precisely the default behavior when using the [Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/), which would also clean up a lot of your code.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go back to the MainActivity onBack click of WalkthroughFragment then while commit your fragment add it to BackStack using this method:

```
FragmentTransaction addToBackStack (String name)
```

This method will do the below operation:

Will Add this transaction to the back stack. This means that the transaction will be remembered after it is committed, and will reverse its operation when later popped off the stack.

You can use it like that

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ftx.replace(R.id.my_container_frame, fragment);
ftx.addToBackStack(null);
ftx.commit();
```

Comment: Please understand my problem

Comment: @buddy check my soltion

Comment: can we connect on Instagram please. You will help me and i will help you defiantly @Taha Gorme

Comment: i am not on instagram

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223194/discussion-between-taha-gorme-and-buddy).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite understand the question but you can try overriding onBackPressed() method.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

You can add intent to go to Home Screen in this method.